# how to solve the following logarithm with both base and value in $x$

Tags: logarithms

$\log_{x - 1} \frac{N}{x} = \log_{49} \frac{N}{2450}$, where $N$ can be considered a constant.

I tried using base changing formula by changing the base on both sides to $49$ but the equation gets overcomplicated. I am wondering if there is a simple way to solve this that I am missing.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Trivially: $\log_{x - 1} 1 = \log_{49} 1$

Comment: If you let $c$ be the right-hand side, then you can get to $(x-1)^c(x)=N$